# ¿Cómo hacer una conexion entre C# y OPC?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

En donde trabajo tengo una máquina y necesito acceder a ella mediante variables Kepware OPC quick client.No tengo experiencia con OPC Server y he estado buscando cómo lograr la comunicación y ejemplos de conexión entre C# y OPC SERVER, pero no encuentro nada que funcione. ¿Alguien me podría ayudar con algo que me sirva para hacer la conexión entre C# y OPC?

Gracias.

Comment: creo que el primer punto aqui es saber que es un OPC Server https://www.matrikonopc.es/opc-servidor/index.aspx

Comment: Hola, ¿qué has intentado hacer? ¿Qué ejemplos has visto y no te funcionan? Sería bueno que colocaras el código para entender mejor tu problema.

Answer (score -1):

Recomendaria hagas uso de librerias que apliquen el `Standard OPC` como ser

[OPCFoundation.NetStandard.Opc.Ua](https://www.nuget.org/packages/opcfoundation.netstandard.opc.ua)

Si analizas el codigo expuesto por esa libreria veras que es el repo de `OPC Foundation`

[OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandard](https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandard)

Veo muchos ejemplos en el

[Quickstart Samples](https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandard/tree/master/SampleApplications/Workshop)

creo que deberias empezar analizando si esta libreria te permite conectar al servico `OPC`